# Using WebView evaluateJavascript is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, webview, android-webview

**Goal**: Set Javascript global variable on website to a JSON object through the given WebView.

**Problem**: I first tried using the code snippet below. I am able to set the global Javascript variable to primitive integer just fine. I am running into issue setting the variable to either a String or JSON object.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class HostActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    webView.apply {
      settings.defaultTextEncodingName = "utf-8"
      settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
      settings.builtInZoomControls = true
      settings.domStorageEnabled = true
      settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
      settings.useWideViewPort = true
      settings.displayZoomControls = true
      isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = true
      isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled = true
      webViewClient = WebViewClientImpl()
      loadUrl("SOME URL")
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

**WebViewClientImpl.kt**

```
class WebViewClientImpl : WebViewClient() {

  override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)

    setGlobalJSVariable(view)
  }

  private fun setGlobalJSVariable(view: WebView?) {
    val globalJSVariable = "javascript: globalJSVariable = "{\"someKey\":\"someValue\"}";"

    view?.evaluateJavascript(globalJSVariable, null)
  }
}
```

**Expected**: I expect to set the global Javascript variable to a specific object.

**Actual**: I get this error in the Logcat:
`I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'", source: <WebView url> (1)`

**Attempt 1**: I have tried:
`val globalJSVariable = """<script>globalJSVariable = 1234567890</script>"""`
However, this does not work with a simple primitive integer, so no chance with it working with a JSON object.

**Attempt 2**: I have also tried using an encoder on the string as well with no luck.

```
private fun setGlobalJSVariable(view: WebView?) {
    val globalJSVariable = "javascript: globalJSVariable = "{\"someKey\":\"someValue\"}";"
    val encodedVariable = Base64.encode(globalJSVariable.encodeToByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT)

    view?.evaluateJavascript(encodedVariable, null)
}
```

**Attempt 3**: Another attempt was with Moshi's serializing library. No luck there either.

Comment: I guess your examples aren't the exact code you used. They don't even compile, because quotes are messed up. I would try to remove "javascript:" - it doesn't make too much sense to me. Also, it seems you tried to create a string in JS instead of just creating an object. Try this: `val globalJSVariable = "globalJSVariable = {\"someKey\":\"someValue\"};"` and let me know. Note that I didn't test this.

Comment: Hey @broot, sorry for the extra double quotes there. This still does not work for me. Logcat says:
```I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1", ...```

Comment: Did you maybe call `JSON.parse(globalJSVariable)` or something similar? Or the website which is loaded to WebView did it?

Comment: If there is some existing code and it requires that `globalJSVariable`is actually a string, not an object, then try this: `val globalJSVariable = "globalJSVariable = \"{\\\"someKey\\\":\\\"someValue\\\"}\";"`

Comment: I have not tried JSON.parse yet. I did try JsonParser.
I tired that existing code you mention, but no luck.